# JS - Creating a cycle function with timed interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and currently trying to create a page that: 

1) is constantly cycling each div within an interval of time. 
2) only the selected div would have the class "selected" in it. 
3) the selected class's data-url is placed in src of the iframe below the divs.

This is my sample html.

```
<div class="content selected" data-url="">
   Website 1
</div>
<div class="content" data-url=""> 
   Website 2
</div>
<div class="content" data-url="">
   Website 3
</div>
<div class="content" data-url="">
   Website 4 
</div>
<iframe id="iframe-container" src="" />
```

It seems most of the solutions on cycles is for hiding and showing divs. Is there a way to use the cycle function and add more codes to make it do what I want?

Comment: Do you want to execute code continuously in intervals? Try `setInterval`

Comment: Did you write anything in JS so far?

Comment: I have created some js, but its only for the on click functionality. For each of the divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sites = document.querySelectorAll('[data-url]');
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
var index = 0;

function moveAlong() {
    sites.item(index).classList.remove("selected");
    index++;
    if (index >= sites.length) index = 0;
    sites.item(index).classList.add("selected");
    frame.src = sites.item(index).dataset.url;
}

setInterval(moveAlong, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
iframe {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected" data-url="http://example.com">
  Website 1
</div>
<div data-url="http://www.w3schools.com">
  Website 2
</div>
<div data-url="http://wikipedia.org">
  Website 3
</div>
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```